# Sprite Kit blurred text (SKLabelNode) rendering

Tags: macos, sprite-kit

I am developing a game on OS X and Sprite Kit.

If you look at the attached screenshot, you'll notice that most of the text appears smudged/blurred. I am using a custom font here, but even using helvetica, the issue is the same. Also notice, that two lines "... visit the Drinking Dragon Inn." and "... leave the city" are not blurred... don't know why.

The scene size is the same as the view/window size, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Any idea of what is going on?

[image: Screenshot of the font issue]

Comment: Do you have any other nodes overlapping your text? Are you using any filters?

Comment: No and no, just regular SKLabelNodes.

Comment: What is the position of the labels? If you are using half numbers, that could be causing the problem.

Comment: No, I am using integers.

Comment: Some things to look at:  Are you scaling the label nodes?  Are they children of a scaled label node?  Are you running a filter effect on the parent node?

Comment: You might consider posting the code that creates those SKLabels.  Also, what font size are you using?  And could this be a retina/non-retina issue?  Does this occur on a retina device as well as on a non-retina device?

Comment: The problem was mainly with a third-party label class, which rendered the text with half-numbers. Then again, just by using a normal SKLabelNode with whole numbers I am still seeing some blurriness for the "Locan" and "Plaza" labels. It goes away if I align them to the left or right for example or by changing font sizes. It must be some kind of half number issue here too, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it without changing size for example. And I only have access to a non-retina display, so I can't test this on a retina display, though I guess the problem would't be present there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your comments, it has to do with half numbers. But not with the placement of the node itself. It happens when you are centering the text. You can solve it by creating a SKSpriteNode subclass which contains an SKLabelNode. Set the SKLabelNodes horizontalAlignmentMode to SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight (or left). Now manually center the SKLabelNode in the SKNode, and round to a whole integer.

(in the below example I init a SKSpriteNode with a transparent texture, this is for debugging use mainly, so I can easily init it with a non-transparent texture to see where its scenter is.)

UPDATE WITH CODE:

```
-(id) init {
    if (self=[super initWithTextureNamed:@"1x1trans.png"]) {

        _textLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Avenir-Light"];
        _textLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;
        [self addChild:_textLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Getters/Setters

-(void) setDelegate:(TextBlock *)delegate {
    [super setDelegate:delegate];
    _textLabel.text = delegate.text;
    _textLabel.position = CGPointMake(floor(_textLabel.calculateAccumulatedFrame.size.width/2), _textLabel.position.y);
}
```

Comment: I haven't thought of that. Thanks Theis!